# Save large amounts of data with Hibernate through a Spring CrudRepository

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, kotlin, crud

I'm trying to use a Spring CrudRepository saveAll() on a large amount of data (Anywhere from 10,000 records to 100,000 records), but I'm experiencing slow performance up to 5 hours to save the records. Are there any suggestions to improve performance?

I have a Spring app written in Kotlin and I'm using this Spring CrudRepository saveAll() on Entities to get them into an Azure SQL Server Database. I have already tried the following
1) Bumping up the jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size up to 100. 
2) Adding jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates and jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts.
3) There are no autoincrement IDs defined on the table.

````
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.IdClass

@Entity
@IdClass(EntityClassId::class)
data class EntityClass (
  @Id
  val manuCode: String,

  @Id
  val catCode: String,

  @Id
  val code: String,

  @Id
  val value: String,

  val language: String,

  val description: String
)

data class EntityClassId (
  val manuCode: String = "",
  val catCode: String = "",
  val code: String = "",
  val value: String = "") : Serializable```


```import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface EntityClassRepository: CrudRepository<EntityClass, String> {

  fun findAllByManuCodeAndCatCode(manuCode: String,
                                              catCode: String) : MutableList<EntityClass>
}```

```EntityClassRepository.saveAll(listOfNewEntities)```


Expecting to be able to save a large amount of entities in a quicker time.
````

Comment: Do you have to use JPA or even JVM to do it? From where are you taking this 100k record to insert?

Comment: Another app posts the data to an endpoint on my app where I consume it and write it out to an Azure Database. I'm just trying to figure out my options.